# How do I calculate the temperature rise in the ferrite core?

Tags: temperature, magnetics, core

This question might seem basic but I would like to state it.

I would like to calculate the operating/Rise temperature of the ferrite core of an inductor.

I am modelling my own bobbins for the core so I need to decide on the material/filament to use for 3D printing which can take the temperature of the core without causing any damage or melting of the bobbins. I looked into it but could not get the answer I am looking for.

Inductor specifications which might be useful for better understanding:

- [E70 core](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/db/fer/e_70_33_32.pdf)
- N87 material
- v= 450VRMS
- I=40A
- f=85kHz
- Litz wire for the windings
- distributed air gap on each leg

Please help me with this, any links or any articles would be great too.

Comment: It's not easy.  You'll have conduction from the windings, which will have AC losses including proximity losses and fringing field losses due to the gaps.  Then there's core loss which will depend on flux density and frequency (and not just the fundamental frequency unless sinusoidal).  Finally there's convection, conduction, and radiation of the heat away from the core.  Figure all those things out and you can calculate the temperature rise.  A finite element magnetics program might be the most accurate way.

Comment: You haven't stated number of turns and given that you must know that AND, because you know the wire type, you must have a value for the copper losses as a starting point.